# I want to set default text in text box.When user type something default text will appear too like

Tags: vb.net

I want to set default text in text box. When user type something default text will appear too like default text is:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ .....  .jpg
```

When user type something in text box as 1 result will show:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\1.jpg
```

Thank

Comment: Would you be prepared to only show the additional text when the control does not have focus and remove it while the user is editing the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the **placeholder** attribute. Use it like any other attribute inside your ASP.net control:

```
<asp:textbox id="txtWithHint" placeholder="C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ .....  .jpg " runat="server"/>
```

At your server side code, append the text entered by user like this.

```
Dim userInput As String = 
                  String.Format("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\{0}.jpg", txtWithHint.text)
```

I hope this will resolve your problem.